# Why can't I call array.0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This code will alert all the properties names in the object a. 0,1,2 and hello.

```
Object.prototype.hello = {};

var a = [1,2,3];

for ( var number in a ) {
    alert( number)
}
```

My question is, I can access the property hello by this syntax:

```
a.hello
```

But why can't I access `a.0` which should be equal to 1. Isn't the array decleration creating "real properties"?

I know that I can access the properties by a[0] and a["hello"]

Comment: side note: never loop over an array with `for...in`, that is for objects only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a syntax limitation. In JavaScript, identifier must not start with number, so `0` is not a valid one. `a.0` will then produce syntax error.

Comment: Ok, so in the for ... in, I don't get the identifers name. So what does I get?

Comment: @SimonEdström `for ... in` enumerates property names, which are arbitrary strings and therefore may or may not be an identifier.

Answer (score 3):

[Because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals):

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($);

Answer (score 2):

Items in an array are accessed using the syntax `myArray[index]`.
The dot notation only allows you to access properties whose names are valid identifiers, and the index of an item in an array, being a number, does not qualify. Therefore, you have to use the more lenient bracket notation.

Comment: Items in the array are objects in the protoype, you just can't access  them with dot notation because they start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript identifiers cannot begin with a digit. The property that you are trying to access is an identifier inside the object.

You will find here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals this fragment:

> Variables
>
> You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application.
>   The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.
>
> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode
>   letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX
>   Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.
>
> Some examples of legal names are Number_hits, temp99, and _name.